# I want to remove the margin below the image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to remove the margin below an image, but
I can't get rid of it no matter what I do.

```
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>screenshot</title>
    <meta name="description" content="screenshot">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <!-- [if lt IE 9] -->
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
    <!-- [endif] -->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="flexline px4">
        <div class="left"> 
            <div class="type1">
                [URL]<br>
                https://www.google.com
            </div>
            <div>
                [Domain]<br>
                www.google.com
            </div>
            <div>
                [title]<br>
                google
            </div>
            <div>
                [date]<br>
                2023/7/7
            </div>
            <div>
                [term]<br>
                365days
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="type1">
                screenshot
                <a href="./ss/image.png" target="_blank" >
                    <img src="./ss/image.png" width="100%">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>

</html>
```

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(100, 200, 250);
}

.center {
    text-align:center
    }

.px1{
    font-size: 40px;
    }

.px2{
    font-size: 70px;
    }

.px3{
    font-size: 25px;
    }

.px4{
    font-size: 30px;
    }

.flexline{
    display: flex;
    }

.left {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 5px;
    /*background-color: rgb(219, 243, 223);*/
    background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
    border-radius: 15px;
    }
  
.right {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 5px;
    /*background-color: rgb(219, 243, 223);*/
    background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
    border-radius: 15px;
    } 

.type1{
    margin: 10px 10px;
}

.type2{
    margin: 10px 10px;
}
```

I want to remove the margin below an image, but
I can't get rid of it no matter what I do, even if I specify a height to the rigth class, the margin does not disappear.It uses flexbox, and as the container on the left grows, the container on the right grows to the same height.If I use flexbox, will both be fixed at the same height?Please help.

Comment: Just set font-size:0px on the this element: <a href="./ss/image.png" target="_blank" style="padding: 0px;font-size: 0px;">